# SQL Azure - what happens with nested transient error handlind?

Tags: sql, azure, transient

I'm starting to use the transient fault block provided by Microsoft for SQL Azure and I'm noticing that some of my functions which have a transient handled block may have reference to other functions with this block also.

I am guessing that the retry wait time will then compound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you mean by `retry time will then compound`?

Each query to the SQL Database is executed with its own Retry Logic. If you have a method or a function call that executes 10 Queries, each one of these 10 Queries will execute with respective retry logic.

If there is transient error while executing just one of the queries. Then wait time will be that wait time. If there is transient error during execution of more than one query, then wait time will be sum of all wait times occurred during execution.

However the transient errors are what their name suggests - `transient`. It is very unlikely that you will encounter a transient error for more than query executed in consecutive order. But if it happens, then yes - the wait times will sum up. However if you execute queries in parallel, or asynchronously, then you don't really sum up wait times.

And finally, retry policy for one query execution, does not affect retry policy for other query execution.